# grep command to know whther the two strings are in specific order

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I was trying to write a shell script to check if two strings are present in a file, also, I'm checking if they are in specific order.

Let's say the `file.txt` has the following text:

```
bcd
def
abc
```

I'm using the command : `grep -q abc file.txt && grep -l bcd file.txt`

This is giving the output `file.txt` when the two strings are present in any order. I'd like to get the output only if `abc` comes before `bcd`. Please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` instead of `grep` to match `abc` only after `bcd`:

```
awk '/abc/{p=NR} p && /bcd/{print FILENAME; exit}' file
```

Comment: It seems working. is there any way I can match only a part of the strings rather than the entire line? `awk '/ab/{p=NR} p && && /bcd/{print FILENAME; exit}' file` isn't giving the output when I removed `c` in `abc`.

Comment: Sorry there should be only single `&&` as in my updated answer. Also `/ab/` will match string `ab` anywhere in the line. Try this: `awk '/ab/{p=NR} p && /bcd/{print FILENAME; exit}' file`

Answer (score 3):

With ***grep*** *PCRE* option:

```
grep -Pzl 'abc[\s\S]*bcd' file.txt
```

- `-z` - treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.

---

If *PCRE* (`-P` option) is not supported on your side:

```
grep -zl 'abc.*bcd' file.txt
```

Comment: I am not allowed to setup PCRE. It's not recognizing the command "P"

Comment: the flag `z` is also not supporting here

Comment: @sbk: Which grep (and which Unix) do you have?

Comment: `-z` is only supported in `gnu grep`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v RS='' '/abc.*bcd/{print FILENAME}' file.txt
```

You may re-assign the RS (record separator) from default `'\n'` to `''`, and start to process the whole file as it is in one record. Then it's no problem to use `/abc.*bcd/` to distinguish if `abc` is ahead `bcd`.

Noted that it would not be recognized successfully if an empty line is in the case, since an empty line between `abc` and `bcd` would split them to different records. That would cause the criterion misjudge.

Comment: That won't work if there is any empty line in the input.

Comment: @anubhava, yes you're right. But why is that the empty line will make the answer not work? Can you give me some hints?

Comment: When RS is set to the empty string, each record always ends at the first blank line encountered. [See this documentation for more details](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html)

Comment: Understood. Thanks for it. I'll delete my answer since it's not working in all kind of cases.

Comment: You can keep the answer, just update that it will work only if there is no empty line in input.